# Probability to draw a given number of red cards in the first $N$ turns, given an initial condition

Tags: probability

I have a deck of 40 cards, 20 red and 20 black. I start a game with 7 cards and each turn I draw one. What is the probability that at turn $N$ I will draw exactly $M$ red cards, supposing that there were $X$ red cards in the first 7?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with the hypergeometric distribution. Whatever happened before the 7 cards is already known, since by knowing how many red cards you obtained in the first 7 draws you automatically know how many black cards you drew (you are the only player). So the situation resets.

Suppose you drew 3 red and 4 black cards in the first 7 draws. Then you have 17 red and 16 black cards left. From here you can estimate the probability that for ex. you draw an additional 5 red cards in the next 10 draws (using R):

```
> dhyper(5,17,16,10)
[1] 0.2920147
```